# Poetry unable to find installation candidates for connectorx

Tags: postgresql, python-poetry, python-polars

i'm using poetry version 1.2.2 and python 3.11
I want to read the sql query using polars like pl.read_sql()
but it requires the connectorx library.
I am able to install that library using pip install connectorx but poetry add connectorx is giving this error:

```
 RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for connectorx (0.3.1)

  at ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\poetry\installation\chooser.py:103 in choose_for
       99│
      100│             links.append(link)
      101│
      102│         if not links:
    → 103│             raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
      104│
      105│         # Get the best link
      106│         chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
      107│
```

Tried clearing the cache of poetry
Tried adding into pyproject.toml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`connectorx` neither provide a wheel file for python 3.11 nor a source distribution from which a wheel could be build. See https://pypi.org/project/connectorx/#files

So there is no way to install it on python 3.11

Comment: You're absolutely right, I figured that out that there's no wheel file for 3.11 so I changed my python version to 3.10 and able to install it now. Thanks very much!

Comment: One year later, and the problem still persists for Python 3.12. Frankly, I'm giving up.